# NLTK Word Tokenize doesn't return anything

Tags: nltk, tokenize, pos-tagger

I am trying to tokenize a sentence, and I believe that the code is correct but there is no output. What could be the problem? Here is the code.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
text = word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")
nltk.pos_tag(text)

text = word_tokenize("They refuse to permit us to obtain the refuse permit")
nltk.pos_tag(text)
```

Comment: Take a look at https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the following packages are missing.

1. punkt
2. averaged_perceptron_tagger

Note: You need to download them for the first time.

Try this..

```
import nltk

nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
text = word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")
print(nltk.pos_tag(text))

text = word_tokenize("They refuse to permit us to obtain the refuse permit")
print(nltk.pos_tag(text))

print("----End of execution----")
```

[Try this on IDE](https://repl.it/repls/MisguidedNoisyDecagons)